# How do you map a "@" as the first character of the JSON string name using object mapping with RestKit 0.20.3?

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

If the JSON looks like this:

```
{ "articles": [
    { "title": "This is a example",
      "@body": "Some text for the body"
    }]
}
```

And your objective-c class looks like this:

```
@interface Article : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* body;
@end
```

This code doesn't work:

```
RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Article class]];
[articleMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ 
    @"title": @"title",
    @"@body": @"body"
}];
```

How do you specify the "@" character for the @body name in the JSON?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean "doesn't work"? What is the intended result and what is the outcome? The answers of these questions would help people to help you.

Comment: Sorry it crashes with this error:[<__NSCFDictionary 0x9522f90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Type.'

Answer (score 1):

You can't really. RestKit uses KVC so `@` in keys has a special meaning. Your best option is to change the JSON. If you can't, [this](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/1384) might help you (but it is limited).